# Drunken font lock in a long-running session

Tags: osx, font-lock

I'm running the emacsformacosx.com build of Emacs 25.2.1 in daemon mode. I connect to it through emacsclient invoked from various tmux sessions in macOS Terminal. `$TERM` is `xterm-256color`. The daemon process is long-running, ideally lasting for days or weeks until a reboot is required.

At first everything is fine, but font locking eventually craps out. Here's an example from an orgmode buffer:

[image: Example of borked font locking]

There is a link around the "This is a link" line. Everything after should be regular text.

It's not orgmode-specific. Other modes exhibit similarly weird effects, as if font lock is getting slightly drunk.

It's not syntax-specific. If I toggle `font-lock-mode`, everything renders correctly but the problem is still present and resurfaces at the next point of syntax highlighting.

I don't think it's my configuration. I'm not doing anything exotic (with font locking, or in general), and my packages are up-to-date.

I can avoid the issue by restarting the daemon, but is there a better solution?

Comment: What happens if you set `font-lock-support-mode` to `nil`? That will slow font-locking down, but it might help with updating - worth a try.

Comment: The main question is if this is a tmux/terminal rendering problem, or if is Emacs has applied some faces incorrectly. To find out, place the cursor in the incorrectly colored text after the link and type `C-u C-x =` and check if there is a `face` text property or overlay at that location.

Comment: The `face` within the incorrectly area is `org-link`. `font-lock-multiline` property is also set. The result is the same whether inside or outside of tmux. But a standalone, GUI emacs instance shows neither property (only `fontified t`) and rendering is otherwise correct.

It's as if the last-used face is being left on. 

I set `font-lock-support-mode` to nil (as well as the other values), but the behavior stayed the same.

Comment: Does it only happen in deamon mode, or does it happen when you run it in a terminal directly?

Comment: Only in daemon mode.

Comment: Can you come up with a recipe where this occurs every time? If so, you could run https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-profiler on it in deamon and normal modes and compare `font-lock-profiler-log` between the two runs.